# Alexa Skill: Trigger Intent after starting skill

Tags: android-intent, alexa-skills-kit

I've started skill programming with Alexa skill via [Alexa Developer Console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console) some days ago.
Therefore I'm not in a that much high level of skill developing and I hope to get help for a question here.

I have a skill to play a stream (m3u). That works great.

My simple code for this is in `index.js`

```
const Radio1 = {
  token: '1',
  url: 'https://[...].m3u',
  metadata: {
    title: 'Radio1',
  },
}
const Radio2 = {
  token: '2',
  url: 'https://[...].m3u',
  metadata: {
    title: 'Radio2',
  },
}

const PlayStreamIntentHandler = {   
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest'   
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
  const stream = Radio1;
  const speechText = `Starting ${stream.metadata.title}`;

  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', stream.url, stream.token, 0, null, stream.metadata)
    .getResponse();
  } 
};
```

This does nothing else than starting my Skill with e.g. `Alexa start MySkillName`
It works, but now I want to trigger after a while - let's say after 10 minutes - another Intent.
It's name is `Radio2Intent` and already defined in "Intents" section.

Also the code is written (very basic):

```
const Radio2IntentHandler = {   
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'Radio2Intent'; 
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
  const stream = Radio2;
  const speechText = `Starting ${stream.metadata.title}`;

  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', stream.url, stream.token, 0, null, stream.metadata)
    .getResponse();
  } 
};

[...]

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
     [...]
     Radio2IntentHandler
)
```

I though, I can change the stream by saying "Change to Radio 2" to Alexa would work, but it does not :(

My Intent

```
{
    "name": "Radio2Intent",
     "slots": [],
     "samples": [
       "Change to Radio 2"
     ]
}
```

Maybe anybody can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [multiple-stream-sample](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/tree/mainline/multiple-streams) from Alexa Team on Github.

All you need to do is use of [Audio Player Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html). The trick is to use `ENQUEUE` instead of `REPLACE_ALL` while adding `AudioPlayerPlayDirective`.

Then you should be able to navigate between your `m3u` streams with "Alexa, Next" and "Alexa, Previous" commands (see [NextPlaybackHandler](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/b1f8074be62568bc0613fb01df60a1815af413b2/multiple-streams/lambda/src/index.js#L146)).

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not exactly that, I want to do.

My goal is to switch to any(!) radio station (defined as m3u before). For example: Alexa, start my skill - now it's starting with radio 1 - fine so far. Then I want to switch to radio 5 (this is not the next) with Alexa, switch to radio 5. Later I want to switch from 5 to 3 with Alexa, switch to radio3.